# How do I clone a private GitHub repo from Travis CI .org

Tags: github, travis-ci, credentials

I am having a difficult time cloning a private repository in my Travis CI script.

How can I supply my credentials to clone a GitHub repository from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to clone a repository with the bare minimum credentials is to use OAuth protocol authentication using a "**Personal Access Token**".

First, you will need to generate a Personal Access Token from your GitHub account that has privilege to the private repository. Then use the following command format to clone the repository using OAuth.

```
git clone https://<personal_access_token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git
```